# mToken detection in linux

Tags: usb, encryption, smartcard

I have bought a **Longmai mToken CryptoIDA 2.0** which it's official site state is supported by Linux and Windows. In windows the token is working fine but on Linux (Ubuntu 19.10 or Ubuntu 19.04 or Ubuntu 16.04) it didn't get detected as smartcard in any usb port. It is showing as [sr1] scsi3-mmc drive: 40x/40x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray. What is the problem and how to solve it

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL (http://ubuntu-news.org/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) and thus off-topic on this site unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  I'd suggest using a LTS release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.   https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Or should I write on any linux distro as I have multiple installed

Comment: Sorry it was 19.10 mistakenly written, but by detection I mean in windows the usb/mtoken is detected as smartcard/smartusb but in ubuntu it is showing sr1 (which is for cdrom as per my assumptions) and I got it from dmesg

Comment: sr1 is not cdrom.  sr1 is the first SCSI device. And ATAPI devices (= cdrom, dvd, bd) are emulated as a SCSI device. SATA is also seen as SCSI on Linux. Also: please do not use the devive name. The digits and letters are assigned as those devices are discovered. Use a label, UUID, or disk ID. `scsi3-mmc ` seems correct to me. multi media card, so flash memory.